# Python error when running SL4A script from Tasker (AttributeError: type object 'Android' has no attribute 'getIntent')

Tags: android, python, sl4a, tasker

I'm trying to call a Python script from Tasker using SL4A on my Android (4.4) phone. I'm using the Run SL4A Script task for this. As a test exercise, I want to pass a string from Tasker and use it (for now just print it) in Python.

According to the link below, this can be done by setting the 'Pass Variables' field in the Run SL4A Script task and picking it up with the Android getIntent method in Python. (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/taskerpro/mQIv1PBu3PU)

Here's my Python script:

```
import android
droid = android.Android
params = droid.getIntent().result[u'extras']
print params[0]
```

However when I run the task I get the following error in SL4A:
AttributeError: type object 'Android' has no attribute 'getIntent'

Anyone know why I get this and how to solve it? I can't find any reference to it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about calling from Tasker, but the Python script runs fine stand-alone on [SL4A Release 6](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/downloads/detail?name=sl4a_r6.apk&can=2&q=) and Python interpreter [Py4A Release 5](https://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/downloads/detail?name=PythonForAndroid_r5.apk&can=2&q=).

If you don't have everything installed yet, here are some [some slides](http://files.meetup.com/1790856/Introduction%20to%20Scripting%20Apps%20on%20Android.pdf) I recently presented at an Android developers meetup.

Comment: Thanks scottt. I've updated both SL4A r6 and Py4A r5 but still get the same error.

Comment: I suggest first getting your script running via the SL4A editor. That will let you know if the issue is something within your script or something caused by the Tasker environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are simply missing the parentheses in your Android imports.

I use:

import android

droid = android.Android()

you can also try:

from android import Android

droid = Android()

this makes Android an object in python properly and you should be able to call the getIntent and other functions properly.

and to save time testing if the android module is functional I also add:

def toast(x):

```
x = str(x)

droid.makeToast(x)
```

then you can pass variables to the newly defined toast(x) function.

Hope I've helped!